# Loop On Exception

Tags: java, loops, exception

I have a custom built API for interacting with their messaging system. But this API doesn't give me any way to confirm that I have established a connection aside from when it is unable to connect an exception will be thrown.

When I receive a exception while connected, I have an exception listener that attempts to reconnect to the server. I'd like this to loop on exception to retry the connection. Doing an infinite loop until I am able to connect, or until the program is closed. I attempted to do this with break labels like so:

```
reconnect: try{
    attemptReconnection();
}catch(Exception e){
    log.error(e);
    break reconnect;
}
```

but that was unable to find the reconnect label for me, and is a bit to close to using a GOTO statement than I would be comfortable putting into production.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proceed this way:

```
do { // optional loop choice
    try{
        attemptReconnection();
        break; // Connection was successful, break out of the loop
    } catch(Exception e){
        // Exception thrown, do nothing and move on to the next connection attempt (iteration)
        log.error(e);
    }
}while(true);
```

If the execution flow reaches the `break;` instruction then that means that you successfully connected. Otherwise, it will keep moving on to the next iteration. *(Note that the loop choice is optional, you can use pretty much any loop you want)*

Answer (score 1):

Have attemptReconnection return true when connection succeds, false otherwise.

The method attemptReconnection  should also catch and log the Exception.

Then :

```
while(!attemptReconnection()){

 log.error("Connection failure");

}
```

Comment: Hmm.. Same concept I had, but this is much cleaner and more proper. Have to say I like this answer more haha.

Answer (score 1):

Can't say I have experience with APIs, but I would think something like this would achieve the result you're after.

```
boolean success = false;
while (!success){
    try{
        attemptReconnection();
        success = true;
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        log.error(e);
    }
}
```

Once `attemptReconnection()` executes without errors, `success` would be set to true and terminate the loop.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest controlling the reconnection attempts not with a while loop but with a scheduled event. This you can easily initiate multiple connections and implement a back off mechanism not to over-consume resources while trying to reconnect

```
private ScheduledExecutorService scheduler;
...

public void connect() {

    for (int i = 0; i < numberOfConnections; i++) {
        final Runnable r = new Runnable() {
            int j = 1;

            public void run() {
                try {
                    final Connection connection = createNewConnection();

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    //here we do a back off mechanism every 1,2,4,8,16... 512 seconds
                    final long sleep = j * 1000L;
                    if (j < 512) {
                        j *= 2;
                    } else {
                        j = 1;
                    }
                    LOGGER.error("Failed connect to host:port: {}:{}. Retrying... in {} millis",
                            host, port, sleep);
                    LOGGER.debug("{}", e);
                    scheduler.schedule(this, sleep, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    Thread.currentThread.interrupt();
                }
            }
        };
        scheduler.schedule(r, 1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }
}
```

Do not forget to do a `scheduler.shutdownNow()` if you want to close the application so as to avoid the treadpool being leaking.

You can even implement a reconnect mechanism once you have been connected and you are disconnected by having the listener execute the connect method in case of a status change on the connection.